# Limit using the definition of a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to show that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{3n-5}{2n-1} = \frac{3}{2}$ by using the definition of a convergent sequence. so far I have,
$\lvert a_n - a\rvert < \epsilon$, for any $\epsilon > 0 $

$\lvert \frac{3n-5}{2n-1} - \frac{3}{2} \rvert < \epsilon $

$\lvert \frac{-7}{4n-2}\rvert < \epsilon$

$ \frac{7}{4n-2} < \epsilon$

But I am struggling to find a way to compare it to a sequence without the -2 in the denominator or how to manipulate it. Any help would be great, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lvert \frac{3n-5}{2n-1} - \frac{3}{2} \rvert < \epsilon $$

$$\lvert \frac{-7}{4n-2}\rvert \color{red}< \epsilon$$

$$ \frac{7}{4n-2} < \epsilon$$

$$4n-2 > \frac7\epsilon$$

$$n> \frac14\left( \frac7\epsilon + 2 \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake there

$$\left| \frac{3n-5}{2n-1} - \frac{3}{2} \right| < \epsilon \implies \left| \frac{-7}{4n-2}  \right| < \epsilon$$

and now it is easy conclude form here.

Comment: Oh yea, sorry, I put the wrong inequality.

Comment: @adsy9 Then you are almost done  form $\frac{7}{4n-2} < \epsilon$ assuming $4n-2>0$ we obtain  $\epsilon(4n-2)>7$ and now it suffices to isolate $n$.

Answer (score -1):

Something of importance to note here is that when you are working on finding the $\epsilon$'s and $N$'s you want to use in the proof you can begin by assuming that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$, but when you go to write the proof you **must not start that way**.

So, you want to try and find an $n$ so that $\frac{7}{4n-2}<\epsilon$. Well, I don't like that fraction. It confuses me. So let's replace it with another fraction that is nicer! We know that $\frac{7}{4n-2}<\frac{7}{n}$ for all $n$ (though we don't technically need for that to be the case). Then, so long as $\frac{7}{n}<\epsilon$ we will be just as good as before.

Comment: Is there a particular reason this received a downvote? It addresses the problem in the OP in a way that generalizes to other problems.